# Laravel 5: How to use button?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm a newbie in laravel 5.. and i don't know how to use button function.. I need to save the data in database but i don't know how to do it.. Thanks for the help!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Create</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name here" name="name"></div>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Author" name="author"></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="action_create"></div>
    <div><textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea</div>
    <div><button type="button">Button</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my route

```
$router->get('create',['uses' => "TestController@create"]);
$router->post('create',['uses' => "TestController@store"]);
$router->get('edit/{blog_id?}',['uses' => "TestController@edit"]);
$router->post('edit/{blog_id?}',['uses' => "TestController@update"]);
$router->get('view',['uses' => "TestController@view"]);
$router->get('/',['uses' => "TestController@index"]);

public function store(InputRequest $input){
    // return 'lkjlasd';
    $new_blog = new Blog;

    $new_blog->fill($input->all());

    if($new_blog->save()){
        echo "save success.";
    }else{
        echo "db communication error";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to start without creating a form will be unable to send anything on your form
The way is your not send anything

**Index**

```
<form method="POST" action="backend" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="InsertData" role="form">
      <div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name here" name="name"></div>
      <div><input type="text" placeholder="Author" name="author"></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Insert"></div>     
</form>
```

**In your route:**

Here you will call your action of your form eg "backend"

```
Route::get('backend','Controller@InsertData');
```

**In your controller**

The controller uses the eloquent in order to save the content in your database

```
    public function updateSocial() { 
        $new_blog = Input::except('_token'); 
        $validation = Validator::make($new_blog, Blog::$new_blog); 
        if ($validation->passes()) {
            $new_blog = new Blog;
                $new_blog->name = Input::get('name');
                $new_blog->author= Input::get('author');
                $new_blog->save();
                Session::flash('insert', 'success'); 
                return Redirect::to('backend'); 
        } else { 
            return Redirect::to('backend')->withInput()->withErrors($validation); 
        } 
    }
```

**In your model**

Will draw variable and here is their validations

```
public static $new_blog = array(
        'name' =>  'required',
        'author' =>  'required',
        );
```

I hope help you

Comment: It's not working sir..this is the error,TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 0):

Extending the anwser on @Jose Cerejo's answer:

Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to the form.

What you doing with your routes is exacly the same as:

```
$router->resource('/', TestController::class);
```

Checkout the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

**EDIT:**

You could use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) to do something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TestController@store']) !!}
<div>
    {!! Form::text('name', null, [ 'placeholder' => 'Enter Name here' ]) !!}
</div>
<div>
    {!! Form::text('author', null, [ 'placeholder' => 'Author' ]) !!}
</div>
<div>
    {!! Form::submit('Insert') !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

It creates the form with the necessary hidden fields for you (like crsf token and a _method field for the update PUT requests)